# Format SQL query to Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, format

So far I have copied and pasted from SQL to Python simple codes where I have used the following formats:

```
sql = ("SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4 "
       "FROM table1 "
       "LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON x = y "
       "LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table3.z = table1.y "
```

However now I have started to copy into Python largest and more complicated SQL codes and I find quite difficult to use the same format as the above as columns start to contain sub-codes. I have seen some python packages that format an SQL code into python and I was wondering which one you suggest or what is the best and quiker way to overcome this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python multiline strings that start and end with three `
```` ```This is a ````

a multi

```
   line
```

string```
and not worry about formatting. This is what i generally use for such purposes but ideally you should go with an ORM

For reference please check

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp

Answer (score 1):

For readability, you can try [this](https://pypi.org/project/format-sql/)

**For example:**

```
sql = """ SELECT country, product, SUM(profit) FROM sales   left join
x on x.id=sales.k GROUP BY country, product having f > 7 and fk=9
limit 5;    """
```

will result in:

```
sql = """
    SELECT
        country,
        product,
        SUM(profit)
    FROM
        sales
        LEFT JOIN x ON
            x.id = sales.k
    GROUP BY
        country,
        product
    HAVING
        f > 7
        AND fk = 9
    LIMIT 5; """
```